# Status table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I know C# and SQL Server well, but I am learning ASP.NET Core 3.1 and building a new API using Entity Framework Core 3.1.4 and code-first migrations.

I'm unsure how to accomplish a specific task: I have a database record that needs to have a "status" associated with it, such as New, Received, Verifying Data, Processing, Sending, Complete, Canceled.

If I were building the database myself, I'd typically make a status table and insert those statuses as records, then point to that record from the record in the other table. I know there has to be a better way to accomplish this with Entity Framework.

I thought about using an enum, but that leaves me without the ability to use spaces in the value displayed to the end user. It also causes issues because EF wants to make an int db column and point to the index of the item in the enum. If the enum is reordered or a value inserted in the middle, it causes issues.

Seems like such an elementary question, but I'm not used to allowing something else to control my database schema.

Comment: you have to save the status as "int" in your table schema and a table to save the statuses you have. last thing you have to seed it with Status Enum values

Comment: If you have any chances for changing or reordering the values of status values I suggest not to use enum. You can have them as a separate table referenced by other table and get the status names either by joining the tables or using status object as a property of the other table class.